# How can one set the background color of a property sheet

Tags: c++, windows, propertysheet

How can I change the background color of a property sheet?  I can change the color of the actual pages by handling the WM_CTLCOLOR... messages but the tabs and other parts of the property sheet seem to be beyond my reach.

Might there be something in the callback?

Here's what it looks like when I handle the WM_CTLCOLOR msgs in the page dialogs.

[image]

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would have thought `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` worked for this. Have you already tried this?

Comment: There's a dialog procedure for the dialog which hosts the control containing the property sheet and each property page has it's own dialog.  I responded to the WM_CTLCOLOR msg in those dialogs with a brush of the desired color.  This colors the individual pages and the main dialog BUT not the property sheet tabs nor that part of the property sheet beyond the property sheet pages.

Answer (score 0):

Tab controls are notoriously difficult to work with. You will likely have to implement an owner-drawn tab control to get the level of customization that you want.