# Styling GUI Objects in Dyalog APL

Tags: dyalog

Using the graphical user interface features of Dyalog APL 16 I'm trying to create a custom theme where all objects are supposed to have a common background color (other than the default gray). The property *BCol* can be set for many objects but I'm stuck when it comes to objects of type *PropertySheet*, *TabControl* and *Button* of style *Push*. Have I missed something or is it due to limitations of the Windows API? Are there available workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these seem to be Windows API limitations:

- [PropertySheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15987086/5306507)
- [TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5569475/5306507)
- [Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745582/5306507) for which [the documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#GUI/Objects/Button.htm) even states clearly that

  > pushbuttons (Style `'Push'`) **ignore** BCol and instead use the standard Windows colour.